# Questions about clusters of two dental stops in PIE

Tags: historical-linguistics, proto-indo-european, hittite

Beekes says a sibilant was inserted between two dental stops in PIE, therefore *-tt-, *-dt- > *-tst- and *-d(h)d(h)- > *-d(h)zd(h)- and the cluster is "*retained as such in Hittite.*" Whereas Hittite seems to have cluster -dst-: PIE *h1éd-t(o) ‘he ate’ > Hitt. ezzasta /edsta/. I am wondering why the reflex in Hitt. is -dst- rather than -tst-.

Besides, according to Shevelov's view, "*For the East­ Central area a transitory stage of tt > ct may be posited, with later simplifica­tion of the positional, extraphonemic affricate c into s.*" How should "extraphonemic" be interpreted? Is it equivalent to "nonphonemic"?

Comment: Some claim that Hittite has both /dz/ and /ts/, but I don’t think that’s a general view; at any rate, I don’t think anyone claims that Hittite is able to show any distinction between /dst/ and /tst/. The root is /ed/, so at least morphophonemically, the form would have a /d/ here as well, but phonetically, it would almost certainly have been [tst].

Comment: The Hittite Inherited Lexicon seems distinct /dst/ and /tst/: "Note that I also interpret the outcome of *-tt- or *-dt- as /-tst-/ and /-dst-/. This is indicated by spellings like az-za-aš-te-ni /ʔdsténi/ ‘you eat’ < h1d-th1e and e-ez-za-aš-ta /ʔédsta/ < *h1ed-t(o)."

Comment: You have to read that in context: Kloekhorst is talking about how not every ⟨z⟩ automatically represents the single underlying phoneme /tˢ/, but he doesn’t say anything about the actual pronunciation of it. He considers that the outcome of PIE _*dt_ and _*tt_ are parallel to the outcome of _*ds_ and _*ts_, except with an extra /t/ after. So _*h₁éd-onti_ ‘they eat’ gives /adantˢi/ with monophonemic /tˢ/, whereas _*h₁éd-si_ ‘you eat’ and _*h₁éd-to_ ‘he ate’ give /ʔedsi/ and /ʔédsta/ with diphonemic /ds/. The /d/ part of that is purely a product of the root having /d/ instead of /t/ – as far as →

Comment: → I know, the actual Cuneiform spellings do not distinguish between /dst/ and /tst/, and I don’t read Kloekhorst’s words as saying that he does either, except on a (morpho)phonemic level. He believes there was some sort of difference between the mono- and diphonemic variants, but that’s it, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interpretation of Hittite `/ts/` is still somewhat of an open question.

First, Hittite cuneiform *could* have distinguished voiced and voiceless stops in many positions…but it didn't. For example, the signs *ta* and *da* are used pretty much interchangeably, even though Sumerian and Akkadian uses them consistently to indicate a voicing difference. However, Hittite scribes *were* consistent (in a way Akkadian and Sumerian scribes never were) in distinguishing between *at-ta* and *a-ta*—that is, single vs double consonants.

This is the distinction that Kloekhorst transcribes as `/t/` vs `/d/`, but only for the sake of easier typography: he doesn't claim there was actually a voicing distinction there. It was almost certainly some sort of length instead.

Now, was there a consistently-written difference between *az-za* and *a-za*? That's less clear. It certainly wasn't as consistent as *at-ta* vs *a-ta*, so it's still debated whether there was a difference between short and long `/ts/`—or whether length mattered in clusters at all! There are ways that length *could* have been indicated in consonant clusters, like writing *ar-at-ta* vs *ar-ta* (VC-VC sequences were avoided except when writing clusters), but these methods don't seem to have been used.

So whether there was any difference between `/dst/` and `/dzd/` and `/tst/` is an open question. If there was, it certainly wasn't indicated in the writing. Kloekhorst uses this transcription because the root was `/ed/` (or maybe `/ʔed/`). But it's very likely that the difference between `/d/` and `/t/` was neutralized in this position, and the choice of which transcription to use is a matter of style more than anything measurable.